# how to put different max character limit on textfields in one View in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have a UIView with 10 UITextFields on it.i want to limit the different max character length on each UItextField.suppose on the first textfield the max length should be 17,for second and third it should be 2.how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Implement a `UITextViewDelegate` with `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText` and return `NO` when the length of the text view's content is equal to or greater than the maximum length. The only exception to this is when the `replacementText` is empty in which case you should always return `YES`

Comment: i have already implemented the method you mention above but it max limit is same for all uitextfields.i want different for different textfields

Comment: You can either use a different delegate for each text view, or use the same delegate but differentiate between different text views

Comment: how do i do this mean use the same delegate but differentiate between different text views

Comment: Store pointers to each text view somewhere, when the function is called the text view which triggered the method is passed in. Compare the passed in pointer against the pointers you have and determine which character limit you need to apply.

Comment: post your attempts at implementing my answer.